# Flex Box. Как заполнить пустоту третьим блоком?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, flexbox

http://prntscr.com/ktl4ov

Там снизу третий блок, но он идет после второго, как заполнить это пустое пространство третьим?

Comment: Просто измените вложенность в html немного и переопределите потом в css немного и все,без потерь

Answer (score 1):

можете показать ваш код?возможно можно бы было разбить на 2 класса допустим "блок-1, блок-3" и "блок-2" и при помощи display:flex общему классу так их и поместите, сделал на коленке,то что на картинке, но суть ясна, я думаю..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: #cont {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: baseline;
}

.content_block {
    padding: 30px 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    font:400 18px fgb;
    flex-basis: 46%;
     box-shadow:
   0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
   -23px 0 20px -23px rgba(120,84,222, 0.16),
   23px 0 20px -23px rgba(120,84,222, 0.16),
   0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}